# libGDX, How to detect touch on device?

Tags: android, libgdx

With this code I can only move with my right arrow on my keyboard. How can I do to move right when I touch on my test device?

```
public void handleInput(float dt){

    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) {
        if (!keyPressed) {
            keyPressed = true;
            if (player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x <= 4) {
                player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0.3f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
        }
    } else {
        keyPressed = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using libGDX and this is not a dublicate...

Comment: please improve your question with more info. When you created the question Stack Overflow has shown a lot of info in how to build a good question